# Stop all threads using threading.Event()

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am creating a multiple threads to execute a function that generates PDF. This process takes a lot of time, so the user has a choice to cancel the execution.

To stop a thread, I know that I can use `threading.Event()` to check if it will be set. However, the process of the function I am executing in my event loop is straight forward/linear (There is no loop to check regularly if the Event is set).

```
--threading class--

    def execute_function(self, function_to_execute, total_executions, execution_time, controller):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.event_list.append(self.event)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.future = self.loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, function_to_execute, self.event, total_executions,
                                                execution_time, controller)


    def stop_executor(self):
        for event in self.event_list:
            event.set()
        self.event = None

        if self._executor:
            self._executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

```
    def *function_to_execute*(self, event, total_execution, seconds=SECONDS_DEFAULT, controller=None):
        self.event = event
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

My problem is that, I can't implement the Event to interrupt the threads without looping to regularly check the Event. 
Is there any other way around to stop all those threads?
Or if I will still use the Event, is there any other logic to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even a non-looping function could implement occasional checks of a flag. What is the function doing when the stop-event is set?

Comment: @user4815162342, yes, but the problem is that when I click the stop button, I need to immediately stop the process. However, since this is a non-looping function, I need to implement the stop-event multiple times. I still dont know how to implement the stop-event for the function.

Comment: But what is the problem with adding the checks to a non-looping function? I don't think there is a magical way for the check to happen on its own, you must implement it...

Comment: @user4815162342 that function also calls another functions that execute big tasks. If for example, I add a checker from the start and at the end of that function, it will still do the process before checking the event. Are we on the same boat? Haha!

Comment: Yes, you need to add the check to all the functions.