# Is it possible to interrupt the main thread using child thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a function that will compute something then put it on a PDF. However, this process takes time. Because of this, we implement stop button for the user to stop the process.

I tried using `thread.Event()`, but the function I am working with is a non-looping function. This means that, I can't regularly check if event is set. (Hard coding the application by simply putting multiple checker will do but nope -- that idea is not accepted).

```
def generate_data(self, event):
      self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.check_event)
      self.thread.start()
      ... 

def check_event(self):
      while True:
           if self.event.is_set():
               self.controller.enable_run_btn_and_tab()
               return
           time.sleep(1)
```

My idea is to create another thread that will regularly check if event is set so I can return and exit the function. However, the above code for `def check_event(self)` will only exit the child thread, not the thread for `generate_date(self)`.

Is there some code or modification in my code to stop the main thread using child thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop all threads using threading.Event()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369844/stop-all-threads-using-threading-event)

Comment: If you don't have control over your work function, isolate it in a subprocess, which can be killed.